# The probability of at least once having gotten 6 heads in a row by tossing a fair coin $n$ times.

Tags: probability

Assuming each coin flip is independent of each other, and chance for heads is $50\%$.

How can we calculate the chance that after $n$ flips having gotten 6 heads in a row at least once?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Seems like calculating for 6 flips, then 7, then 8 would be pretty easy and might lead to some fruitful ideas.

Comment: @Arby Yes, I gave a practical answer for how to calculate it on the duplicate marked answer since there were already two good derivations.